# What is the root span of Dwarf Southern Magnolia 'Little Gem'?

Tags: trees, planting, roots, magnolia

I can't seem to find any consistent information on the root structure of these guys.  We were given one as a housewarming gift and would like to get it into the ground as soon as possible, however I'm not sure how far to place it from my fence to avoid future issues.

What diameter should I expect the root system to be, so that I can plant it far enough from my deck and fence to avoid issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for this tree, but as a general rule, tree roots spread 2-3x the width of the branches. It looks like [your tree will be about 15' wide (diameter)](http://www.sunnygardens.com/garden_plants/magnolia/magnolia_1817.php). So if you plant it 30' from your fence you should be well clear of any root-related issues. (Closer *might* be ok, I don't know how aggressive these roots are.)

Comment: That's great, one of the links I had seen expect 3-4x spread out, which would have made it hard to plant anywhere.